# Question about VSCODE Azure AD B2C extension

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the following VSCODE extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADB2CTools.aadb2c

My b2c custom policies are broken into multiple files. Means I have a reference like below in my files:

```
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_<NAME OF THE PARENT POLICY></PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
```

I am exploring its two important feature:

- "Go to Definition" "
- "Find All References"

However, I am noting the features are single file only, they can't go across multiple files.

Am I missing anything or the extension is not capable of processing inheritance across multiple files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it should also work across files. Make sure you open the folder containing all custom policy files in VS code (File -> Open folder), not just one file.